# Display a required text input when Other is selected

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I need to add a text input that displayed only when the other is selected. And make this input required if it is shown. One thing more, I need to enter that input to the same table in the database. Can anyone help? Please!

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">`enter code here`
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offs et-2"> 
            <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" required>
                <option value="">Please select your country</option>
                <option value="A">Country A</option>
                <option value="B">Country B</option>
                <option value="C">Country C</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gpsingh">Next</a>
             </div>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details instead of using comments. Thanks.

Comment: My thought would be to use jQuery and an input field that is set invisible by default. This could be done by either setting the field "type' attribute as hidden or using the CSS rule `display: none`. Add an onchange attribute to the select element and toggle the visibility of the hidden field if "other" is selected. There are several ways to make this happen, even without using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offs et-2"> 
            <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" required >
                <option value="">Please select your country</option>
                <option value="A">Country A</option>
                <option value="B">Country B</option>
                <option value="C">Country C</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>

             <input type ="text" id="country_other" style="display:none">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gpsingh">Next</a>
             </div>
     </div>
</form>

<script>
$("#country").change(function(){

    var value = this.value;
    if(value =='Other')
    {
        $("#country_other").show();
        $("#country_other").prop('required',true);
        $("#country_other").val('');

    }
     else
    {
       $("#country_other").hide();  
       $("#country_other").prop('required',false);
       $("#country_other").val('');
    }    

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked well but it doesn't show as required?